# Error in ==> fsolve at 254 fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

Tags: matlab

Could you please explain me my mistakes and how I can fix this issues?
I tried to solve the system of differential equations using shooting method.
I have two .m files.

```
function dfdx=fff(x,f)
dfdx = zeros(size(f));
Pr=1;
dfdx=[f(2);
f(3);
-3*f(1)*f(3)-2*(f(2))^2+f(4);
f(5);
-2*Pr*f(1)*f(3)]
 end
```

And the second

```
function  g = u(v1,v2)
x0 = 0; xf = 7;
   f0 = [0 0 v1 0 v2];
   [t, Func] = ode45(@fff, [x0, xf], f0);

   g = [Func(end,3),
   Func(end,5)]
 end
```

I can find the two
When I tried to find the missing initial conditions using fsolve, I get

```
>> myfunc = @u

myfunc = 

@u

>> fsolve(myfunc,[0,0])
 ??? Input argument "v2" is undefined. Error in ==> u at 3 f0 = [0 0 v1 0 v2]; Error in ==> fsolve at 254 fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});
```

Comment: `myfunc` is a *variable* pointing to an anonymous function so you don't need the @ when using `fsolve` because then MATLAB tries to execute `myfunc` as a *function*.  Simply call `fsolve(myfunc, [0 0])`

Comment: I tried it and I got




     >> fsolve(myfunc,[0,0])
     ??? Input argument "v2" is undefined.

      Error in ==> u at 3
       f0 = [0 0 v1 0 v2];

      Error in ==> fsolve at 254
           fuser = feval(funfcn{3},x,varargin{:});

          Caused by:
            Failure in initial user-supplied objective function evaluation.                FSOLVE cannot continue.

Comment: If you check out the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html#inputarg_fun) for `fsolve` you'll see that it expects your function to accept 1 input argument. Your function (`u`) accepts 2.

Comment: The way you are calling `fsolve` is that you are supplying `v1` and `v2` as a vector of elements.  However `myfunc` is expecting **two arguments**.  `fsolve` requires that the function to solve has **one argument** as input.  Change your function header to `function g = u(v)` then at the beginning of the code before you do anything, do `v1 = v(1); v2 = v(2);`.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand you corrext. Where I need to do:
v1 = v(1); v2 = v(2)   ?

Comment: @AntonRudakovskyi modify `u` to accept one input. Then place a `keyboard` on the first line of `u` and inspect what that one input looks like.

Comment: Thank you very march for clarification!